# How to solve flicker for fixed menu when using easyResponsiveTabs.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When used fixed menubar and easyResponsiveTabs.js in my [project](http://amniltech.com.np/investment/agriculture)  there is flicker in menubar when scrolled down. How to solve this issue? I tried using `jquery.noConflict()` but it didn't work. Can anyone please give some idea as what is to be done?

Comment: Which browser are you referring to? The site looks okay in Firefox.

Comment: @ArinCool i am referring to chrome ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the solution. I have added the following css and the problem was solved.

`.navbar-fixed-top {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}`